# How image capturing with Pygame actually works?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

My goal is to set up a webcam with Raspberry Pi to be active during a certain time (let's say 2 minutes). During this time I should be able to capture a still image at any time and save that image to a folder. I chose to work with pygame. My project is about capturing an image as soon as a sensor has been triggered, so it needs to be very responsive.

According to the documentation for Pygame camera [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) it says:

> `open()`
>
> Opens the camera device, attempts to initialize it, and begins
>   recording images to a buffer. The camera must be started before any of
>   the below functions can be used.
>
> `get_image()`
>
> Pulls an image off of the buffer as an RGB Surface. It can optionally
>   reuse an existing Surface to save time. The bit-depth of the surface
>   is either 24 bits or the same as the optionally supplied Surface.

So for my case, the `get_image()` simply seems to pull out the first image captured after `start()` has been called. My question is, how can I reach the buffer with all captured images or how does the capturing actually work? I can't find a solution for capturing and saving a still image (at any time) after in between I call `start()` and `stop()` on the pygame camera. Since the `start()` function initiates during a few seconds, it is simply too slow to just call `start()`, `get_image()` and `stop()` after one another. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

See my python code below:

```
def activateCapturing:
    pygame.init()
    pygame.camera.init()
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(320,180))
    cam.start()

    pngdata = None
    imageAsbytes = []
    activated = True

    while activated:
        if readSensor():
            img = cam.get_image()
            pygame.image.save(img, "/tmp/image.png")
            activated = False

     with open("/tmp/image.png", 'rb') as f:
            pngdata = f.read()
            imageAsbytes = bytearray(pngdata)

    cam.stop()
    return imageAsbytes
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You simpy do not stop the camera after capturing one image.

See https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/CameraIntro.html.

`get_image()` gets the image the camera currently sees from the buffer - the buffer NOT being "all pictures since start()" but simply the currently viewed image.

You use `stop()` after your 3s of "capturing window" to stop aquiering more images.

If you are after performance, you might want to scroll down that page and review the section about  **Capturing a Live Stream** - if you did the same (w/o displaying the stream) and just saved 1 image to disk when needed you should get a decent framerate.

Api: [get_image()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html#pygame.camera.Camera.get_image)

Comment: But this is not the case when I try it? I mean I call start() and after get_image() but it seems it is always returning the first image after start() is called. I don't get why? For example if I start() the camera, and I 10 seconds later try to capture an image, I still get an image that was taken 10 seconds ago. This is not what I am trying to achieve.